# DJango: Textarea/Form get, process and show

Tags: python, django, text-processing

Good evening, i'm currently working on a small DJango project, and am currently facing an issue:
The whole of the project is to provide a textarea to the user:

*1- let the user write down the text that will be worked with.*

*2- store the data to process/work on it using python.*

*3- store the processed data on another variable.*

*4- show the text on a second textarea provided on screen.*

Currently, I've tried using a simple  to get the information and store it, but the site keeps spinning and there's no progress

**Base .html section with the textareas:**

```
    <section id="det">
        <div class="theText">
            <textarea id="text" placeholder="Type/Paste to Summarize"></textarea>
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Start</button>
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit">Clean</button>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    
        <div class="theText">
            <textarea id="text" placeholder="Your summarized text"></textarea>
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Export</button>
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit">Copy</button>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**Alternative tried:**

```
<form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for='TPre'>PreSummarizarion</label><br>
            <input id="TPre" name="TPre" type="text"><br>
            <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Current views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, "first/home.html",{
        "text":text,
    })

def taking(request,tex,tex_slug):
    tex= textPre.objects.get(slug = tex_slug)
    return render(request, "first/home.html", {
        "tex":tex
    })
```

**Current models on the django project:**

```
from django.db import models

class textPre(models.Model):
    preText = models.TextField()
    #preText2 = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    
class textPost(models.Model):
    posText = models.TextField()
    #posText2 = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.preText}"

#def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
#    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
#    self.slug = self.id
#    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Whereas; preText would be user to store the data, and posText will contain the new text that was processed using python.

Questions:
1- How can I store the user input from the textareas on to a variable to work on it using python?
2- How can I show the processed information on the second textareas space?

(Note: Relatively new to DJango here, have tried a couple other methods and course materials, but to no avail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From scratch. You do not need two `Models`, just one with two fields is fine. To make a process over one of the two fields you can override [`.save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) method of the model:

models.py

```
def process_text_field(text):
    processed_text = text.lower()
    processed_text = 'Processed Text:\n' + processed_text
    return processed_text

class TextProcess(models.Model):
    original = models.TextField()
    processed = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.processed = process_text_field(self.original)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For example, by writing a function that would process the `original` field and assign the result to `processed`.

[views.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/#the-view)

```py
def index(request):
    obj_instance = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        original = request.POST.get('text')
        obj_instance = TextProcess.objects.create(original=original)

    return render(request, "index.html",{'text': obj_instance})
```

index.html

```py
{% block content %}
<section id="det">
    <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="theText">
            <textarea name="text" placeholder="Type/Paste to Summarize"></textarea>
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Start</button>
            <button >Clean</button>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    </form>

    {% if text %}
    <div class="theText">
        <textarea placeholder="Your summarized text">{{text.processed}}</textarea>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

The same template is rendered, for both entering and displaying information. The difference is that on `GET` requests there is no object instance created (handled at the `view`), so only the first block (to enter the text) will be displayed (because of the `if` condition).

If you are wondering about the `URL`, that is just a way to obtain the full path by using the [reverse resolution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls):

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
]
```

I must say that there are other approaches, you could do the processing in other places for example in the `view`. But in programming you always want to separate your logic as much as possible, following the `single responsibility` principle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Will try it out and perform the corrections needed!